# Limit CPU usage during transformers inference

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I have an application that calls multiple `python` processes `python3 Main.py -args ...` (but at most n processes)

I want to use a `transformers` model in that process for inference. However, when I include it, if one process runs, the other processes are stuck, because the first process that runs

```
nlp = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")
```

uses all CPU cores.
Is there a way to limit the cores `pipeline()` uses? (e.g. use max 50% of available cpu cores; exact % to be determined)

I have read that cpu load balancing can be better if I do multiprocessing from within 1 process, but each of my python processes does not know about the other, and changing the whole workflow of the application is not really an option.

Or is there any other way to avoid one `pipeline` process clogging the CPU usage?

Needless to say, I currently run the `huggingface` model on a CPU, since the current setup doesn't have a GPU.

Comment: As CPU cache is a thing, you may end up with better throughput if you let them run as they do now, after each other.

Comment: Be that as it may, I would like to test out the alternative if possible. It might be preferable from a usecase perspective for me, if the processes that do not necessarily use the `transformers` model can finish parallely without being stuck, at the cost of the `transformers` process taking a bit longer

Comment: Using 50% of cores doesn't mean a bit longer runtime, it means 2x runtime for that particular task. After the other processes finish, "their" 50% of cores won't do anything. Anyway, based on https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.2/en/parallelism, I'm not fully convinced if the amount of details provided here is really enough for answering this question.